# rxjs join and filter an observable based on values from a different observable

Tags: rxjs

How do I filter an observable using values from another observable, like an inner join in SQL?

```
class Item {
    constructor(public name: string public category: string) {
    }
}

class NavItem {
    constructor(public key: string public isSelected: boolean = false) {
    }
}

// Build a list of items
let items = of(new Item('Test', 'Cat1'), new Item('Test2', 'Cat2'))
            .pipe(toArray());

// Determine the unique categories present in all the items
let navItems = from(items)
               .pipe(mergeAll(),
                     distinct((i:item) => i.category),
                     map(i=>new NavItem(i.category)),
                     toArray());
```

I'm building a faceted search so let's say that in the UI, the "Cat1" NavItem is selected, so I want to produce an observable of all the items that have that category.  After filtering down to the selected NavItem, I'm not sure how to bring in the Items, filter them down and spit out only those Items that mach a selected category.  Here's what I have:

```
let filteredItems = navItems.pipe(
   mergeAll(),
   filter(n => n.isSelected))
   // join to items?
   // emit only items that match a selected category?
```

Expected result would be

```
[{name: 'Test', category: 'Cat1'}]
```

Comment: Where's the Observable with the selected item?

Comment: That's navItems.  I build that when the page is initialized and the isSelected property is false by default and is bound to a list of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got back around to looking at this and I figured out how to solve this.  I needed to use switchMap to join the observables together in the same context.  Then I can use map to emit all relevant items:

```
let filteredItems = from(items)
   .pipe(mergeAll(),
         switchMap((i) => navItems
              // Get only navItems that are selected
             .pipe(filter(ni => ni.isSelected),
                   // Convert back to array so I can if there are any selected items
                   // if zero, then show all items
                   toArray(),
                   map((nav) => {
                     if(nav.lengh > 0) {
                         // If the item's category matches, return it
                         return nav.some(x => x.key == i.category) ? i : null;
                     }

                     // If no categories were selected, then show all 
                     return i;
                   })
             }),
           // Filter out the irrelevant items
           filter(x => x !== null),
           toArray()
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to select a certain `navItem` representing a certain category and then select all the `items` which have such category.

If this is true, than you can consider to create a function or method such as this

```
selectedItems(categoryId) {
   return items.pipe(filter(item => item.category === categoryId));
}
```

Once you click the `navItem` then you raise an event which references the `navItem` and therefore the category id you are interested. You have then to call `selectedItems` function and pass the category id you selected. This will return an Observable which emits all the items of the category you have selected.

Comment: I have a lot more descriptors to sort off of than just the category and I also need to support rematerializing the navigation state from session storage so I was hoping for more of a single handler.

Comment: Do you mean that the use can have different selection criteria, category being one of them but not the only one? And that once a selection criteria is chosen and a selection value is given, e.g, a specific category, than all other selection criteria are recalculated and shown to the user?

Comment: Precisely. The final list is an intersection of each of the separate criteria partitions. Each partition is an AND and each partition is made up of ORs.  Ex. An Item can be of Category 1 or Category 2 and must be either Blue or Red. A non rx way would be  to do a nested for loop iterating over each partition finding which ones are selected, then looping over the items and filtering out the array. The next partition picks up the filtered array and filters it further in the same nested manner